# Column header as value in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've tried a few different things based on previous answer, but all of my results come up empty.since so few people specify their program and I can't figure out if its just syntax errors that I can't see, I'm not going to share the queries I've tried. (Who knows how far off I may have been.)

My table headers are
pland, Sun, Moon, Mercury, Venus, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune

The values for pland are the dates and the planetary columns have text containing numbers that look like "6 sa 15" and "10 ge 15 Rx"

I need a query that will put it all into 3 columns: pland, plannme, plans where the value for 'plannme' is the column header and the 'plans' is value for the corresponding date and planet.

I've tried pivot/unpivot solutions that were previously given to other questions, but none of them seem to give me any results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm sure the answer is sitting right in front of me.

Sample data is:

```
pland        Sun          Moon
.......     .........   ........
1/1/1900     10 cp  9    2 cp 24
```

What I want is

```
Pland       Plannme      Plans
........    ........   ........
1/1/1900     Sun       10 cp 9

1/1/1900     Mercury   2 cp 24
```

Comment: have you tried a simple google search.. in regards to `Sql Basics` try something like the following `Select Sun AS '3', Moon as '3', etc... and you will see that the yields.. you need to look up how to use the `AS` key word in regards to Selecting values / Initializing their values.. [SQL Basics Tutorial](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-select-statement.htm)

Comment: No, spent two hours looking at other peoples options without knowing any about SQL, Seriously, if Google had the answer I wouldn't be here.

Comment: I really think that you should provide an exact example of the data that you are working with and or passing.. also provide your exact Sql Statement.. I think that you are doing something incorrectly ..

Answer (score 2):

Use `Cross Apply` with `table valued constructor` to turn your column headers to rows. Something like this.

```
SELECT pland,
       plannme,
       plans
FROM   yourtable
       CROSS apply (VALUES ('Sun',Sun),
                           ('Moon',Moon),
                           ('Mercury',Mercury),
                           ('Venus',Venus),
                           ('Mars',Mars),
                           ('Jupiter',Jupiter),
                           ('Saturn',Saturn),
                           ('Uranus',Uranus),
                           ('Neptune',Neptune)) cs (plannme, plans)
```

**Sample Demo**

```
CREATE TABLE #cs
  (
     pland DATE,
     Sun   VARCHAR(50),
     Moon  VARCHAR(50)
  )

INSERT #cs
VALUES ('1/1/1900','10 cp  9','2 cp 24' )

SELECT pland,
       plannme,
       plans
FROM   #cs
       CROSS apply (VALUES ('Sun',Sun),
                           ('Moon',Moon)) cs (plannme, plans)
```

**Result**

```
pland       plannme plans
----------  ------- --------
1900-01-01  Sun     10 cp  9
1900-01-01  Moon    2 cp 24
```

Comment: I tried that, too, and it leaves me with an empty table. I literally just copied you rquery and replaced the table name. Do you think its some kind of data format issue?

Comment: can you add sample data

Comment: can you add that in question with expected output

Comment: Your demo worked fine. But the cross apply is still having issues with my table. I'm just going to assume that its a formatting issue in the cells?! I'm really at a loss at this point. I've never had so many different attempts still provide me with an empty table. I even fiddled with the original data and reloaded it into the db in case there was something that was missed in the original clean up, but still nothing.

Thanks a ton for helping.